# Can't switch from staic IP to DHCP in nodemcu lua

Tags: lua, nodemcu

wifi.sta.setip({ ip = "192.168.0.111", netmask = "255.255.255.0",gateway = "192.168.0.1"})
with above we can set static IP,
but by mistake if someone enters the netmask/gateway/ip a digit or to wrong (eg:netmask = "255.255.2.0" ) we have no way of detecting. only way is to

by re entering correctly
rebooting
(How to clear static IP configuration and start DHCP)

so it would be nice if we can detect the status somehow like with wifi.sta.status() do.

Comment: I cannot make sense of your question. what do you want to detect? a faulty ip configuration? just read the ip or even better verify the ip befor setting it. what status do you want to check? how is setting the ip and who are you? how does DHCP help with a faulty static ip configuration? either you use static ips or dynamic ips

Comment: i just want to switch between static IP to DHCP

Answer (score 0):

> How to clear static IP configuration and start DHCP

[wifi.sta.clearconfig()](https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/release/modules/wifi/#wifistaclearconfig)

> Clears the currently saved WiFi station configuration, erasing it from
> the flash. May be useful for certain factory-reset scenarios

Not sure if this also deletes the ip but you can probably just set the ip to `"0.0.0.0"` befor you reconnect.

Comment: no wifi.sta.clearconfig() do nothing and   I just want to switch between static IP to DHCP

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `Wi-Fi.sta.autoconnect(1)` to activate DHCP client at ESP STA side and get IP parameters from AP DHCP server.